# Centering nav menu breaks dropdown sub-menu's

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to center this nav menu without breaking the drop-down `li` elements.

My demo: http://jsbin.com/tosayosino/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Removing the `float:left;` from `.jetmenu li` works and centers the menu, but then there are problems when popping out of mobile mode back into desktop mode (the menu stays stacked instead of floating the `li` elements horizontally.

Using `position:relative;` and then `left:50%;` and `right:50%;` for the `div` and `ul` works to center things too, but then the drop-down menu is constrained to the width of the menu item name and squashes all the sub-categories together (I want the drop-down to be full page-width).

My HTML:

```
<nav class="hz-cats-menu">
    <ul class="jetmenu blue">
        <li>
            <a href="view_category.asp?cat=CATID">CATEGORY</a>
            <div class="megamenu full-width text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="view_category.asp?cat=CATID"><div class="col1">CATEGORY</div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="view_category.asp?cat=CATID">CATEGORY</a>
            <div class="megamenu full-width text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="view_category.asp?cat=CATID"><div class="col1">CATEGORY</div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="view_category.asp?cat=CATID">CATEGORY</a>
            <div class="megamenu full-width text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="view_category.asp?cat=CATID"><div class="col1">CATEGORY</div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My CSS:

```
/*
NAME: Jet Responsive Megamenu 
AUTHOR PAGE: http://codecanyon.net/user/marcoarib
ITEM PAGE: http://codecanyon.net/item/jet-responsive-megamenu/5719593
*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic);
@import "font-awesome.css";

/* MENU CONFIGURATION
**********************************************************/
.jetmenu{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background: #333333;
    line-height: 1;
}
.jetmenu li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.jetmenu a{
    -o-transition: all .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
    transition: all .3s linear;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 10;
}
.jetmenu > li > a{
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.jetmenu > li:hover > a,
.jetmenu > li.active > a{
    background: #e0e0e0;
    color: #555;
}
/* DROPDOWN CONFIGURATION
**********************************************************/
.jetmenu ul.dropdown, 
.jetmenu ul.dropdown li ul.dropdown {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;   
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    min-width: 134px;
    background: #333333;
}
.jetmenu ul.dropdown{
    top: 60px;
}
.jetmenu ul.dropdown li ul.dropdown{
    left: 100%;
    top: inherit;
}
.jetmenu ul.dropdown li{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.jetmenu ul.dropdown li a{
    width:100%;
    padding: 12px 24px 12px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.jetmenu ul.dropdown li:hover > a{
    background: #e0e0e0;
    color: #555;
}

/* dropdowns to left side */
.jetmenu ul.dropdown li ul.dropdown.left{
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
}

/* SUBMENU INDICATORS
**********************************************************/
.jetmenu .indicator{
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
}
.jetmenu ul li .indicator{
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 1px;
    left: 10px;
}

/* MEGAMENU
**********************************************************/
.jetmenu > li > .megamenu{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
    width: 25%;
    /* top: 60px; */
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
    z-index: 99;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* megamenu list */
.jetmenu li > .megamenu ul{
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu ul li{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 0;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu ul li.title{
    margin: 0 0 8px;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #666;
}

/* megamenu h5 */
.jetmenu li > .megamenu h5{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* megamenu links */
.jetmenu li > .megamenu a{
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s linear; 
    -moz-transition: color 0.3s linear; 
    -o-transition: color 0.3s linear; 
    transition: color 0.3s linear; 
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu a:hover{
    color: #dedede;
}

/* megamenu images */
.jetmenu  .megamenu img{
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.3s linear; 
    -moz-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    transition: border 0.3s linear;
}

/* to fix right attribute on submenus (menu aligned to left (default)) */
.jetmenu > li.fix-sub > .megamenu,
.jetmenu > li.fix-sub > .megamenu.half-width,
.jetmenu > li.fix-sub > .dropdown{
    right: 0;
}

/* MEGAMENU WIDTHS
**********************************************************/
.jetmenu > li > .megamenu.half-width{
    width: 50%;
}
.jetmenu > li > .megamenu.full-width{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

/* MEGAMENU FORM CONFIGURATION
**********************************************************/
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form{
    width: 100%;
}

/* megamenu inputs */
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form input[type="text"],
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form textarea{
    padding: 5px;
    color: #999;
    background: #444;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: solid 1px transparent;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.3s linear; 
    -moz-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: border 0.3s linear;
    transition: border 0.3s linear;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus,
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form textarea:focus{
    border-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form textarea{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]{
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #444;
    color: #777;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s linear; 
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s linear; 
    -o-transition: background 0.3s linear; 
    transition: background 0.3s linear; 
}
.jetmenu li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background: #e0e0e0;
    color: #555;
}

/* MEGAMENU GRID SYSTEM
**********************************************************/
.megamenu .row{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.megamenu .row:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.megamenu .row:before,
.megamenu .row:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    line-height: 0;
}
.megamenu .row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.megamenu .row .col1,
.megamenu .row .col2,
.megamenu .row .col3,
.megamenu .row .col4,
.megamenu .row .col5,
.megamenu .row .col6{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    <!--margin-left: 2.127659574468085%;-->
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}
.megamenu .row [class*="col"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.megamenu .row .col1{
    width: 14.893617021276595%;
}
.megamenu .row .col2{
    width: 31.914893617021278%;
}
.megamenu .row .col3{
    width: 48.93617021276595%;
}
.megamenu .row .col4{
    width: 65.95744680851064%;
}
.megamenu .row .col5{
    width: 82.97872340425532%;
}
.megamenu .row .col6{
    width: 100%;
}

div.col2:hover {
    background-color: #02b8fa;
}

div.col1:hover {
    color: #888;
    background-color: #e7ecf5;/*#7291ca;*/
}

a.q7 {
   font-size: 1.4em;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   padding: 25px;
}

a.q7:hover {
   /*background-color:#02b8fa;*/
}

span.q7 {
   font-size: 1.4em;
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

span:q7:hover {
   /*background-color: #02b8fa;*/
}

/* RIGHT ALIGNMENT (MENU ITEM)
**********************************************************/
.jetmenu > li.right{
    float: right;
}
.jetmenu > li.right > .megamenu,
.jetmenu > li.right > .megamenu.half-width,
.jetmenu > li.right > .dropdown{
    right: 0;
}

/* to fix right attribute on submenus (menu aligned to right) */
.jetmenu > li.jsright{
    float: right;
}
.jetmenu > li.jsright.last > .megamenu,
.jetmenu > li.jsright.last > .megamenu.half-width,
.jetmenu > li.jsright.last > .dropdown{
    right: 0;
}

/* ICONS (FONT AWESOME)
**********************************************************/
.jetmenu > li > a > i{
    line-height: 23px !important;
    margin-right: 6px;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
}

/* COLLAPSIBLE MENU
**********************************************************/
.jetmenu > li.showhide{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #999;
    background: #333;
}
.jetmenu > li.showhide span.title{
    margin: 15px 0 0 25px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    float: left;
}
.jetmenu > li.showhide span.icon{
    margin: 17px 20px;
    float: right;
}
.jetmenu > li.showhide .icon em{
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #999;
}

/* STYLES
**********************************************************/

/* blue */
.blue > li:hover > a, .blue > li.active > a{    background: #2e67b1; color: #fff; }
.blue ul.dropdown li:hover > a{ background: #2e67b1; color: #fff; }
.blue li > .megamenu form input[type="text"]:focus, .blue li > .megamenu form textarea:focus{ border-color: #2e67b1; }
.blue li > .megamenu form input[type="submit"]:hover{ background: #2e67b1; color: #fff; }
.blue li > .megamenu a:hover{ color: #FFF;/*#333333;*//*#02b8fa;*/ }


/* RESPONSIVE LAYOUT
**********************************************************/
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .jetmenu > li{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > a{
        padding: 15px 25px;
    }
    .jetmenu a{
        width: 100%;
        background: #333;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    }
    .jetmenu ul.dropdown, 
    .jetmenu ul.dropdown li ul.dropdown{
        width: 100% !important;
        left: 0;
        position: static !important;
        border: none;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    }
    .jetmenu ul.dropdown li {
        background: #fff !important;
        border: none;
    }
    .jetmenu ul.dropdown > li > a{
        padding-left: 40px !important;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > .megamenu{
        width: 100% !important;
        position: static;
        border-top: none;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > .megamenu .row [class*="col"]{
        float: none;
        display: block;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 15px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > .megamenu .row:first-child  [class*="col"]:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > .megamenu .row{
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .jetmenu > li > ul.dropdown > li > a{ padding-left: 40px !important; }
    .jetmenu > li > ul.dropdown > li > ul.dropdown > li > a{ padding-left: 60px !important; }
    .jetmenu > li > ul.dropdown > li > ul.dropdown > li > ul.dropdown > li > a{ padding-left: 80px !important; }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    .jetmenu > li > .megamenu{
        width: 100% !important;
        left: 0 !important;
    }
}

body {

font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color: #3e343c;
background: #efeeeb, #ffffff, #efeeeb, #ffffff;
font-weight: 400;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background: #efeeeb, #ffffff, #efeeeb, #ffffff;
max-width: 100%;
min-width: 320px;
overflow-x: hidden;

}
A.menu {
    color: #3b3239;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px;
}
/*A:menu:over:: When a user passes their mouses over them.*/    
A.menu:hover {
    color: #fbf9f2;
    background: #5a2149;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*A:menu-bottom:: Controls the way the Links in the footer display before a user clicks or mouses over on them.*/    
A.menu-bottom {
    color: #3e343c;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
/*A:menu-bottom:over:: When a user passes their mouses over them.*/     
A.menu-bottom:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu-bottom {
    width: 300px;
    height: 125px;
    float: left;
}
li#menu-bottom {
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
/*A:: Controls the way the all Links without an associated style display before a user clicks or mouses over them.*/     
A {

color: #3e343c;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 400;

}
/*A:hover:: When a user passes  their mouse over them.*/        
A:hover {
    color: #5a2149;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#mainContent #home {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px !important;
    padding:10px 0 0;
}
.accent-color {
    color: #5a2149;
}
.accent-bg-color {
    background: #e2e2e2;
    color: #000;
}

#mainContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#mainContainer .wrapper { max-width:1200px; margin:0 auto;}
nav {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px #cecece;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px #cecece;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px #cecece;
z-index:999;
position:relative;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    /*line-height: 49px;*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
#mainContent {
    float: left;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100% !important;
}
ul#desktopMenu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 50px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 15px;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}
ul#desktopMenu li {
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
ul#desktopMenu li:last-child { border-right:none;}
ul#desktopMenu li:hover {
    background: #FFF;
}
ul#desktopMenu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
ul#desktopMenu li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#desktopMenu li ul {
display: none;
position: fixed;
/*top: 222px;*/
/*border: 1px solid #EEE;*/
background: #ffffff  ;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px; 
margin-left: -12px;
 width: 250px; 
z-index: 99999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #666; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #666;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #666;
}
ul#desktopMenu li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

ul#desktopMenu li ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border:none !important;
}

ul#desktopMenu li ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #f15a29;

}
ul#desktopMenu li ul li a {
    color: #333;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: block;
    font-size:14px;
}
ul#desktopMenu li ul li:hover {
    background: #fcfcfc  ;
}
```

My JQuery:

```
/*
NAME: Jet Responsive Megamenu 
AUTHOR PAGE: http://codecanyon.net/user/marcoarib
ITEM PAGE: http://codecanyon.net/item/jet-responsive-megamenu/5719593
*/

(function($){

    jQuery.fn.jetmenu = function(options){
        var settings = {
            indicator: true,
            speed: 300,
            delay: 0,
            hideDelay: 0,
            hideClickOut: true,
            align: "left",
            submenuTrigger: "hover",
            scrollable: true,
            scrollableMaxHeight: 400
        }
        $.extend( settings, options );

        var menu = $(".jetmenu");
        $(menu).wrap("<div class='jetmenu-wrapper'></div>");
        var menuWrapper = $(".jetmenu-wrapper");
        var lastScreenWidth = windowWidth();
        var bigScreen = false;

        $(menu).prepend("<li class='showhide'><span class='title'>MENU</span><span class='icon'><em></em><em></em><em></em><em></em></span></li>");

        if(settings.indicator == true){
            $(menu).find("a").each(function(){
                if($(this).siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").length > 0){
                    $(this).append("<span class='indicator'>+</span>");
                }
            });
        }

        screenSize();

        $(window).resize(function() {
            if(lastScreenWidth <= 768 && windowWidth() > 768){
                unbindEvents();
                hideCollapse();
                bindHover();
                if(settings.align == "right" && bigScreen == false){
                    rightAlignMenu();
                    bigScreen = true;
                }
            }
            if(lastScreenWidth > 768 && windowWidth() <= 768){
                unbindEvents();
                showCollapse();
                bindClick();
                if(bigScreen == true){
                    rightAlignMenu();
                    bigScreen = false;
                }
            }
            if(settings.align == "right"){
                if(lastScreenWidth > 768 && windowWidth() > 768)
                    fixSubmenuRight();
            }
            else{
                if(lastScreenWidth > 768 && windowWidth() > 768)
                    fixSubmenuLeft();
            }
            lastScreenWidth = windowWidth();
        });

        function screenSize(){
            if(windowWidth() <= 768){
                showCollapse();
                bindClick();
                if(bigScreen == true){
                    rightAlignMenu();
                    bigScreen = false;
                }
            }
            else{
                hideCollapse();
                bindHover();
                if(settings.align == "right"){
                    rightAlignMenu();
                    bigScreen = true;
                }
                else{
                    fixSubmenuLeft();
                }
            }
        }

        function bindHover(){
            if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) || window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0 || settings.submenuTrigger == "click"){                     
                $(menu).find("a").on("click touchstart", function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation(); 
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent("li").siblings("li").find(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).fadeOut(settings.speed);
                    if($(this).siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").css("display") == "none"){
                        $(this).siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).delay(settings.delay).fadeIn(settings.speed);
                        return false; 
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).fadeOut(settings.speed);
                        $(this).siblings(".dropdown").find(".dropdown").stop(true, true).fadeOut(settings.speed);
                    }
                    if($(this).attr("target") == "_blank" || $(this).attr("target") == "blank"){
                        window.open($(this).attr("href"));
                    }
                    else{
                        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
                    }
                });

                $(menu).find("li").bind("mouseleave", function(){
                    $(this).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).fadeOut(settings.speed);
                });

                if(settings.hideClickOut == true){
                    $(document).bind("click.menu touchstart.menu", function(ev){
                        if($(ev.target).closest(menu).length == 0){
                            $(menu).find(".dropdown, .megamenu").fadeOut(settings.speed);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else{
                $(menu).find("li").bind("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).delay(settings.delay).fadeIn(settings.speed);
}).bind("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).delay(settings.hideDelay).fadeOut(settings.speed);
});
            }
        }

        function bindClick(){
            $(menu).find("li:not(.showhide)").each(function(){
                if($(this).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").length > 0){
                    $(this).children("a").bind("click", function(e){
                        if($(this).siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").css("display") == "none"){
                            $(this).siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").delay(settings.delay).slideDown(settings.speed).focus();
                            $(this).parent("li").siblings("li").find(".dropdown, .megamenu").slideUp(settings.speed);
                            return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            $(this).siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").slideUp(settings.speed).focus();
                            firstItemClick = 1;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        function showCollapse(){
            $(menu).children("li:not(.showhide)").hide(0);
            $(menu).children("li.showhide").show(0);
            $(menu).children("li.showhide").bind("click", function(){
                if($(menu).children("li").is(":hidden")){
                    $(menu).children("li").slideDown(settings.speed);
                    scrollable(true);
                }
                else{
                    $(menu).children("li:not(.showhide)").slideUp(settings.speed);
                    $(menu).children("li.showhide").show(0);
                    $(menu).find(".dropdown, .megamenu").hide(settings.speed);
                    scrollable(false);
                }
            });
        }

        function hideCollapse(){
            $(menu).children("li").show(0);
            $(menu).children("li.showhide").hide(0);
            scrollable(false);
        }   

        function rightAlignMenu(){
            $(menu).children("li").addClass("jsright");
            var items = $(menu).children("li");
            $(menu).children("li:not(.showhide)").detach();
            for(var i = items.length; i >= 1; i--){
                $(menu).append(items[i]);
            }           
            fixSubmenuRight();
        }

        function fixSubmenuRight(){
            $(menu).children("li").removeClass("last");
            var items = $(menu).children("li");
            for(var i = 1; i <= items.length; i++){
                if($(items[i]).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").length > 0){
                    var lastItemsWidth = 0;
                    for(var y = 1; y <= i; y++){
                        lastItemsWidth = lastItemsWidth + $(items[y]).outerWidth();
                    }
                    if($(items[i]).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").outerWidth() > lastItemsWidth){
                        $(items[i]).addClass("last");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function fixSubmenuLeft(){
            $(menu).children("li").removeClass("fix-sub");
            var items = $(menu).children("li");
            var menuWidth = $(menu).outerWidth();
            var itemsWidth = 0;
            for(var i = 1; i <= items.length; i++){
                if($(items[i]).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").length > 0){
                    if($(items[i]).position().left + $(items[i]).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").outerWidth() > menuWidth){
                        $(items[i]).addClass("fix-sub");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function unbindEvents(){
            $(menu).find("li, a").unbind();
            $(document).unbind("click.menu touchstart.menu");
            $(menu).find(".dropdown, .megamenu").hide(0);
        }

        function windowWidth(){
            return document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth || window.innerWidth;
        }

        function scrollable(flag){
            if(settings.scrollable){
                if(flag){
                    $(menuWrapper).css("max-height", settings.scrollableMaxHeight).addClass("scrollable");
                }
                else{
                    $(menuWrapper).css("max-height", "auto").removeClass("scrollable");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}(jQuery));

      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           $().jetmenu({
                indicator: false,
                speed: 300,
                delay: 100,
                submenuTrigger: "hover"
           });
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you call jQuery's .show(), which adds an inline `display:block;` style. We can fix this by adding a callback to the function to empty the display declaration:

```
    function hideCollapse(){
        $(menu).children("li").show(0,function(){
          $(menu).children("li").css("display","");
          $(menu).children("li.showhide").hide(0);
        });
        scrollable(false);
    }
```

Comment: Does this fix apply to the current code I have, or with the `left:50%;` and `right:50%;` thing I was trying?

Comment: It applies to the code you linked to. All I did was remove the `float: left` from `.jetmenu li` and made the above modification to your JS.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote you more than once. Thank you!

Comment: Haha, so do I :) Keep in mind jQuery sneaks a lot of inline styles in with its animations, and may have unintended consequences.